# How to use Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.FindReplaceRequest?

Tags: c#, google-api

I do not know if you can help or not, but I will try)
I am writing a C # program that works with the Google Sheets API. I ran into a problem, namely: unfortunately very little information on working with the Google API :(
Now, I need examples of how the Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.FindReplaceRequest request works, unless of course this is what I need.
The user enters data in the text field, after which the program must send a request to Google Sheets on Google Drive, find all the cells in which the entered data is located and delete or simply erase the lines with the coincidence of this data. I understand that FindReplaceRequest works best for this, but I can’t find an example of working with it, and in the directory at https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/csharp/latest/index.html very little information about this :(

I would be very grateful if you help solve this problem :)
Have a nice day!:)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: And please be careful when selecting tags for your questions. C is a *very much* different language from C#. So please edit your question to improve it, and fix the tag.